# Hugo Nested loop to iterate through multi-level YAML

Tags: yaml, hugo

I have page front matter with multiple levels. My page front matter looks like this:

```
grids:
- template: section
  background_image: "/uploads/2018/05/01/q-mark.png"
  rows:
  - template: row
    stack-columns: tablet-s
    cols:
    - template: column
      title: "Column-1 Title"
- template: section
  background_image: "/uploads/2018/05/01/lk.png"
  rows:
  - template: row
    stack-columns: tablet-s
    cols:
    - template: column
      title: "Column-2 Title"
    rows:
  - template: row
    stack-columns: tablet-l
    cols:
    - template: column
      title: "Column-3 Title"
```

I can display the first-level template name for both of my grids:

```
{{ range .Params.grids }}
   {{ .template }}
{{ end }}
```

How can I return the template name of rows and cols within the loop?

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. You can use a nested range to access parameters with multiple levels:

```
    {{ range .Params.grids }}

      <p>Grid template name: {{ .template }}</p>

        {{ range .rows }}

          <p><strong>row template name: </strong>{{ .template }}</p>

          {{ range .cols }}

            <p><em>col template name:</em> {{ .template }}</p>

          {{ end }}

        {{ end }}

    {{ end }}
```

This displays:

Grid template name: section

**row template name:** row

*col template name:* column

Grid template name: section

**row template name:** row

*col template name:* column